# $service->people->get('me') throws error: 'Access not Configured'

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api-php-client

What am I missing here? I have Google APIs Client Library for PHP uploaded to the server in my App Engine project. The app .php I'm using starts with the following:

```
  require_once 'Google/Client.php';
  require_once 'Google/Service/Plus.php';
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("ApplicationName");
  $client->setDeveloperKey("APP_KEY");
  $service = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
  $me = $service->people->get('me');
  print "ID: {$me['id']}\n";
```

Yet, the only result I get is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key...
Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.' in /base/data/home/apps/...
```

If I expand it to:

```
  require_once 'Google/Client.php';
  require_once 'Google/Service/Plus.php';
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setClientId('CLIENT_ID');
  $client->setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET');
  $client->setApplicationName("projectName");
  $client->setDeveloperKey("DEVELOPER_KEY");
  $service = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
  $client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
  $me = $service->people->get('me');
  print "ID: {$me['id']}\n";
```

I get the error message: `...Invalid Credentials'...`

Obviously the first thing I did was to activate the Google+ API in my developers console. Why is it still throwing errors? This despite running the script after the perfectly functioning Login script for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this question is obvious but in addition to have activated the API in the developers console, have you changed the Application name and API key in your code?

```
$client->setApplicationName("ApplicationName");
$client->setDeveloperKey("APP_KEY");
```

You can obtain the API key in **APIs & auth**->**Credentials** in your project console at https://console.developers.google.com

Comment: Oh yes. Just don't want to publish that stuff here.